# An example computation of etale cohomology

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, spectral-sequences, jacobians

(edited for clarity)

In a comment on a response to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7318/etale-cohomology-and-l-adic-tate-modules), moonface states the following: "Even if you tried to compute H^2 [etale with Z/5Z-coefficients] of a surface fibered in genus 2 curves over a base curve X, then (to compute the cohomology of X with coefficients in the relevant local system) you have to pass to a 125-fold covering of X and compute the Jacobian of that beast."

Would someone be willing to explain this further?  Given the importance of etale cohomology and the difficulties in working with it, I would really love to see the details of this spelled out.

Comment: In that question, we were working with mod $5$ coefficients. Also, $125$ should have been $625$. Finally, it is not "equivalent": you need only a piece of the cohomology of the cover. Specifically, if $f : X \rightarrow C$, let $C'$ be the $5$-torsion in the relative Jacobian; its Galois group is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GSp}(\mathbb{F}_5)$,  and you need roughly the piece of the cohomology of $C'$ through which $G$ acts by the standard representation. 

Comment: David-

The way you wrote this question is extremely confusing.  I think it would have been really helpful to include part of moonface's comment as an actual quote.

Comment: Correction to previous comment: The cover $C' \rightarrow C$ defined by $5$-torsion in relative Jacobian isn't Galois; indeed, we are only interested in a "certain piece" of its cohomology, but I'm not sure how to find this "piece" without passing to the "Galois closure"... 
And the Galois closure of $C' \rightarrow C$ is a cover of monstrous degree indeed. 

Comment: @Ben: I wasn't sure about the etiquette for quoting other people's answers to previous questions, hence the elliptical wording.  I have edited it for clarity.

Comment: @Moonface: Ahhh, let me guess - by a Leray spectral sequence, computing H^2(X) is reduced to computing H^1(C,H^1(fiber)), and since H^1(fiber) is a local system of $\mathbb{F}_5^{4}$'s you trivialize it by passing to a $5^4$-fold cover.

Comment: David- My personal feeling is that if you said it on MO (or any public forum), and haven't deleted it, then it's fair game to quote.  

